# Subclassing numpy : numpy methods return ndarray instead of the sublassed type?

Tags: python, numpy, subclassing

I was able to subclass numpy :

```
class myary(np.ndarray):
def __new__(cls, arg1, arg2) : 
   .....
        obj = super(myary, cls).__new__(cls, shape=(arg1,), dtype=np.int)
        ....
        return obj
```

it works, but the problem is when I apply numpy functions (like np.concatenate(),np.stack() .... etc) 
the output is ndarray instead of myary.
I implemented `__array_wrap__`, so np.sort, np.add ... work, but not the one I mentioned above.

```
def __array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context=None):
    return super(self.__class__, self).__array_wrap__(out_arr, context)
```

How to force that all numpy methods return whatever I pass as input.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like adapting a `class.__array_function__(func, types, args, **kwargs)` is the way to go as of version 1.16 of NumPy according to [this scipy reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#numpy.class.__array_function__). That description has a helpful (though sparse) example for how to implement `numpy.concatenate` and `numpy.broadcast_to` which made it easy to implement for me! At its simplest (and even more sparse), here's how to handle numpy.concatenate and return an instance of your class:

```
    import numpy as np

    class MyClass:
        def __array_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs):
            if func == np.concatenate:
                < do stuff here for concatenating your class >
                return < result of stuff done of type MyClass>
            else:
                return NotImplemented
```

As a side note, when I implemented `np.concatenate`, I was confused as to how numpy knew to call my method when I provided a list of my subclasses as input (instead of an instance of my subclass). I found this helpful--this method is called whenever a numpy array function is called, and decides whether to use your implementation as follows (note the importance of returning `NotImplemented` if you're not handling a given function):

> 1. NumPy will gather implementations of `__array_function__` from all
>      specified inputs and call them in order: subclasses before
>      superclasses, and otherwise left to right. Note that in some edge
>      cases involving subclasses, this differs slightly from the current
>      behavior of Python.
> 2. Implementations of `__array_function__` indicate that they can handle the operation by returning any value other than `NotImplemented`.
> 3. If all `__array_function__` methods return `NotImplemented`, NumPy will raise `TypeError`.