# How to avoid an object that subclasses NumPy's ndarray being "demoted" to a regular ndarray when placed in a containing ndarray?

Tags: python, subclass, numpy-ndarray, dtype

I created a subclass of NumPy's ndarray, in order to associate metadata with the array.

If I want to store multiple of these objects:

- Everything is fine if I store them in a regular list
- When I try to store them in an outer NumPy ndarray instead, each object is converted back down to a regular NDArray and the metadata is lost.

Is there a way to store these elements in an outer NDArray?

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime


class TaggedData(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls,
                data: np.ndarray,
                name: str = None,
                timestamp: datetime.datetime = None):

        # The basic object is a numpy array
        obj = np.asarray(data).view(cls)

        # Transfer over the rest of the data
        obj.name = name
        obj.timestamp = timestamp

        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):

        if obj is None:
            return

        self.name = getattr(obj, 'name', None)
        self.timestamp = getattr(obj, 'timestamp', None)


d1 = TaggedData(np.random.rand(10,10),
                name='Analysis1',
                timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
print(f"1st data is named: {d1.name}")

d2 = TaggedData(np.random.rand(10,10),
                name='Analysis2',
                timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())

# Even though the default addition doesn't do what I want, it doesn't lose the tags
d_sum = d1+d2
print(f"Name of the summed data is: {d_sum.name}")

# Create a NumPy array of these two TagedDatas
#data_array = np.array([d1, d2], dtype=TaggedData)
data_array = np.array([d1, d2], dtype=object)

print(f"The first data object has name: {data_array[0].name}")
```

The first print statement shows that the object does contain the metadata.

The second print statement shows that the **add** method is doing the right thing.  From my understanding, this works because of the **array_finalize** method.

The third print statement shows that the elements of the array are now back to np.ndarray and have no metadata.  The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tagged_data.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(f"The first data object has name: {data_array[0].name}")
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Another post -- [Subclassing numpy : numpy methods return ndarray instead of the sublassed type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162273/subclassing-numpy-numpy-methods-return-ndarray-instead-of-the-sublassed-type) -- may point to a solution being that I could create a new class for the outer array (called, like, TaggedDataList), but...  is that the best way?  Seems like overkill.