# Cannot copy an object that is a subclass of float

Tags: python, floating-point, copy, subclass

**The specific question**:  I created a class in Python that is a subclass of float, here as an example that just adds a "name" field.  The class seems to work as I hoped, but I noticed that I canot do a copy.copy() or copy.deepcopy() on these objects.  The class and copy command are:

```
import copy


class NamedFloat(float):

    def __new__(cls, val: float, name: str):
        if val is None:
            return None
        else:
            return super().__new__(cls, val)

    def __init__(self, val: float, name: str):
        self.name = name


x = NamedFloat(4.23, 'ClientA')
x2 = copy.copy(x)
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Noughbee\Python\nf\named_float.py", line 18, in <module>
    x2 = copy.copy(x)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Noughbee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\copy.py", line 102, in copy
    return _reconstruct(x, None, *rv)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Noughbee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\copy.py", line 265, in _reconstruct
    y = func(*args)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Noughbee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\copyreg.py", line 105, in __newobj__
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: NamedFloat.__new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Is there a missing dunder method or something else that could help this class play nicely with copy?

**The meta question**:  I really like the idea of classes that subclass floats or NumPy ndarrays, because the primary data is a single thing -- a float or an NDArray -- that happens to have metadata associated with it...  and with these subclasses, I can write "value" when I want to access the primary thing and "value.name" or whatever when accessing the metadata.  It's interesting and, to me, makes cleaner code when you can write familiar math expressions with the quantity and "forget" it is carrying around metadata.  But this question and a somewhat related one I posted recently ([How to avoid an object that subclasses NumPy's ndarray being "demoted" to a regular ndarray when placed in a containing ndarray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75960041/how-to-avoid-an-object-that-subclasses-numpys-ndarray-being-demoted-to-a-regu)) may be telling me that this "trick" isn't all that robust and I should just get over being smitten by it.  What say you?

Answer (score 2):

Try defining `__getnewargs__()` to tell the default implementation of `__copy__()` how to reconstruct instances of `NamedFloat`:

```py
In [25]: import copy
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: class NamedFloat(float):
    ...:     __slots__ = ('name',)
    ...: 
    ...:     def __new__(cls, value, name):
    ...:         self = super().__new__(cls, value)
    ...:         self.name = name
    ...:         return self
    ...: 
    ...:     def __getnewargs__(self):
    ...:         return float(self), self.name
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: x = NamedFloat(4.23, 'ClientA')
    ...: y = NamedFloat(4.23, 'ClientB')
    ...: x2 = copy.copy(x)
    ...: y2 = copy.copy(y)
    ...: print('x', id(x), x, repr(x), type(x), x.name)
    ...: print('x2', id(x2), x2, repr(x2), type(x2), x2.name)
    ...: print('y', id(y), y, repr(y), type(y), y.name)
    ...: print('y2', id(y2), y2, repr(y2), type(y2), y2.name)
x 4371847520 4.23 4.23 <class '__main__.NamedFloat'> ClientA
x2 4371844592 4.23 4.23 <class '__main__.NamedFloat'> ClientA
y 4371844208 4.23 4.23 <class '__main__.NamedFloat'> ClientB
y2 4371854624 4.23 4.23 <class '__main__.NamedFloat'> ClientB
```

Comment: this looks better than overloading `__copy__` as it'll do the right thing with `pickle`.  I'd also suggest specifying `__slots__` as shown. see docs for object-model and pickle

Answer (score 1):

The `copy.copy` function doesn't know about the signature of your class's constructor, which is why it raises that error, but it allows you to supply your own shallow copy implementation via a `__copy__` method:

```
    def __copy__(self) -> 'NamedFloat':
        return NamedFloat(self, self.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error, you should define a default value for the parameter `name`:

```py
import copy


class NamedFloat(float):
    def __new__(cls, val: float, name: str = None):
        if val is None:
            return None
        else:
            return super().__new__(cls, val)

    def __init__(self, val: float, name: str):
        self.name = name


x = NamedFloat(4.23, "ClientA")
x2 = copy.copy(x)
```